# Lightning Knowledge Migration - No primary custom field found

Tags: knowledge, migration-tool, migration, articles, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to get my lightning Articles migrated from classic to lighting. Now I am trying to use the Lightning Knowledge Migration assistant to migrate the articles. I received the below error.

1. Something went wrong. Try again. If you’re still having trouble,
   contact     Salesforce Customer Support for help.
2. No primary custom field found.

Can anyone please guide me about these errors?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have you gone through the pre-migration checklist? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_migration_tool_plan.htm&type=5

Comment: Yes! i have gone through this link already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had a managed package installed related to knowledge. i uninstalled that package and completed my migration.